# Equivalent to TYPE=“OVSPort” DEVICETYPE=“ovs” OVS_BRIDGE=br-ex in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bridge, openstack, openvswitch

Is there an equivalent to TYPE="OVSPort" DEVICETYPE="ovs" OVS_BRIDGE=br-ex in Ubuntu 14.04?

The system is OpenStack Icehouse with 3 nodes (controller, network, compute1) each on a VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine. OpenSwitch is used to create bridges on the network node.

In CentOS the file would be: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1

Currently /etc/network/interfaces contains for eth1 and br-ex:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
up ifconfig $IFACE 0.0.0.0 up
up ip link set $IFACE promisc on
down ip link set $IFACE promisc off
down ifconfig $IFACE down

auto br-ex
iface br-ex inet static
address 10.0.3.21
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.3.2
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

In ovs-vsctl show (OpenVSwitch is used for bridging, br-ex is on eth1)

```
34ffa9a7-8825-4e63-bfcd-c231c34862b3
Bridge br-tun
Port br-tun
    Interface br-tun
        type: internal
Port patch-int
    Interface patch-int
        type: patch
        options: {peer=patch-tun}
Port "gre-0a00011f"
    Interface "gre-0a00011f"
        type:     gre                                                                                                            
        options: {in_key=flow, local_ip="10.0.1.21", out_key=flow,     remote_ip="10.0.1.31"}                                    
Bridge br-int                                                                                                                    
fail_mode: secure                                                                                                            
Port patch-tun                                                                                                               
    Interface patch-tun                                                                                                      
        type: patch                                                                                                          
        options: {peer=patch-int}                                                                                            
Port br-int                                                                                                                  
    Interface br-int                                                                                                         
        type: internal                                                                                                       
Bridge br-ex                                                                                                                     
Port "eth1"                                                                                                                  
    Interface "eth1"                                                                                                         
Port br-ex                                                                                                                   
    Interface br-ex
        type: internal
ovs_version: "2.0.2"
```

Comment: Could you explain the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the [Debian ifupdown script](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/master/debian/ifupdown.sh) into:

`/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/openvswitch`

& have a look at the [README for instructions](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/master/debian/openvswitch-switch.README.Debian) on how to configure `/etc/network/interfaces`

You should also create a symlink for `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/openvswitch` to point to the ifupdown script in `if-pre-up.d`

These scripts are also integrated into [openvswitch in Alpine Linux](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?pkgname=openvswitch&arch=x86_64&repo=main) (which also uses the Debian ifupdown scheme for networking).